# How to know a position (.txt)

Tags: python

i wonder how to know , a position inside the .txt when I read.

this is my txt

> cat dog monkey bird

this my printing

> Word: cat  Position:  line 1 , word 1 (1,1)

any idea?

Comment: The position of ....  _(to be continued with Ignacio's comment)_

Comment: position where a word was written

Comment: He wants to search for a word, and then print the line_no and word_no.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This would work for this given file:

```
blah bloo cake
donky cat sparrow
nago cheese
```

The code:

```
lcount = 1
with open("file", "r") as f:
    for line in f:
        if word in line:
            testline = line.split()
            ind = testline.index("sparrow")
            print "Word sparrow found at line %d, word %d" % (lcount, ind+1)
            break
        else:
            lcount += 1
```

Would print:

```
Word sparrow found at line 2, word 3
```

You should be able to modify this quite easily to make a function or different output I hope.

Although I'm still really not sure if this is what you're after...

Minor edit:
As a function:

```
def findword(objf, word):
    lcount = 1
    found = False
    with open(objf, "r") as f:
        for line in f:
            if word in line: # If word is in line
                testline = line.split()
                ind = testline.index(word) # This is the index, starting from 0
                found = True
                break
            else:
                lcount += 1
        if found:
            print "Word %s found at line %d, word %d" % (word, lcount, ind+1)
        else:
            print "Not found"
```

Use:

```
>>> findword('file', "sparrow")
Word sparrow found at line 2, word 3
>>> findword('file', "donkey")
Not found
>>>
```

*Shrug* Not the best method I'll give it that, but then again it works.

Comment: Instead of catching an exception, use `in` to check if the element is part of the list or use `find` and check the return value.

Comment: Added the `if .. in` part instead of `try .. except`, thanks. Not using find() here as it would return the character position, not the actual word (At least, that's what it's doing for me).

Comment: great! its better for me, because, first I got all word in a dictionary. Thanks everyone

Answer (score 5):

foo.txt:

```
asd
asd
asd
ad
I put returns between .......
asd
sad
asd
```

code:

```
>>> def position(file,word):
...     for i,line in enumerate(file): #for every line; i=linenumber and line=text
...         s=line.find(word) #find word
...         if s!=-1: #if word found
...             return i,s # return line number and position on line
...
>>> position(open("foo.txt"),"put")
(4, 2) # (line,position)
```

Comment: Blerg, I forgot that you could do `for i, line` for a second there. +1 for you!

Comment: -1 Downvoted because it offers a complete solution without any comment on what the function is actually doing.

Comment: @Helper Method, I thought that Python is clear enough, but added comments now, thanks :).

Answer (score 1):

**Basic idea**

1. Open the file
2. Iterate over the lines
3. For every line read, increment some counter, e.g. `line_no += 1`;
4. Split the line by whitespace (you will get a list)
5. Check if the list contains the word (use `in`), then use `list.index(word)` to get the index, store that index in some variable `word_no = list.index(word)`
6. print `line_no` and `word_no` if the word was found

There are a lot better solutions out there (and more `pythonic` ones) but this gives you an idea.